# Remove duplicated pairs from SQL table

Tags: sql

I have a table sample is mentioned below:

[image: Sample dataset]

This table basically has 2 duplicates i.e. the distance between Hyderabad and Bangalore same with Mumbai and Delhi.

I want to remove these duplicates from my table. Is there a way to do this with SQL?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `not exists` and `or`:

```
select t.*
from t
where source < destination or
      (source > destination and
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.source = t.destination and
                         t2.destination = t.source and
                         t2.distance = t.distance
                  )
       );
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

Comment: can you explain more this code `source < destination` and `source > destination`

Comment: I think Nitin is looking for a DELETE statement

Comment: @Abdelhedihlel . . . Those are pretty basic comparisons.  I don't understand your question.